# jQuery UI Selectable: get the text of the selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This code if from the jQuery selectable UI (https://jqueryui.com/selectable/#serialize). How do I modify this to append the `text` value in the selected instead of the index.

I tried many ways unsuccessfully:

1. `var index = $("#selectable li").text();` # appends everything
2. `var index = $("#selectable li").html();` # this appends the first item and stops

```
$(function () {
    $("#selectable").selectable({
        stop: function () {
            var result = $("#select-result").empty();
            $(".ui-selected", this).each(function () {
                var index = $("#selectable li").index(this);
                result.append(" #" + (index + 1));
            });
        }
    });
});


    <ol id="selectable">
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
    </ol>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation for `.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

> Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched
>   elements, including their descendants

From the [documentation for `.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/):

> Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements

---

You could try this:

```
$("#selectable").selectable({
    stop: function () {
        var text = $(this).children(".ui-selected").map(function () {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get().join('; ');
        $("#select-result").text(text);
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BF9Gx/)

This uses the [`.map()` function](https://api.jquery.com/map/) to get the text of each selected item. That returns a jQuery object which actually contains string objects, rather than DOM elements, so the [`.get()` function](http://api.jquery.com/get/) is used to get the array of strings. Then the [array's `.join()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) is used to combine the strings.

Comment: Yes I modified your example to work but can you explain why this is how it's done? Why couldn't I just call `.text()` (I'm learning jQuery) So your thought process in solving the problem is welcomed.

Comment: @feed_me_code - You could just call `.text()` to get the combined text of all the selected items as shown in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BF9Gx/1/), but then there are no separators. That's just how the `.text()` function works when called on multiple elements. Getting the text in an array gives you more flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#selectable")selectable({
    stop: function () {
        var text += $(this)children(".ui-selected").map(function () {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get().join('; ');
        $("#select-result").text(text);
    }
});
```